# The の in のに and なのに

Tags: meaning, set-phrases, copula

I've heard that the の in のに and なのに is the general-noun　の (I don't remember the word for it.). So why, in that light, does the meaning of the two make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The particle construction　～（な）のに expresses the **adversative**, i.e. in English *(al)though*, *even though*, etc.

The の in ～のに and ～なのに is a suffix that functions as a nominalizer. の turns any inflected expression into a noun, and なの does the some for expressions that cannot be inflected. This happens in order to make the attachment of grammatical markers possible that usually do not directly attach to the expressions, or that do so with a different grammatical meaning. The に is **dative/locative** case, which only appear with nominals.

```
 攻撃されたのに、冷静に行動した。
 Even though (he) was attacked, he acted calmly.
```

攻撃された is an inflected expression (a passivized verb), hence のに.

```
 重要な発見なのに、無視された。
 Though an important discovery, it was ignored.
```

発見 cannot be inflected, hence なのに is required.

Some linguists believe that the separation of のに in の and に is not entirely correct because both particles must be present in order to express the adversative. The adversative meaning also does not follow from meaning composition, i.e. combining the nominalizing property of の with dative/locative に does not result in an adversative reading.
That の has a nominalizing property can be seen in other examples, such as

```
 太郎が行かなかったのを知らなかった。
 (I) didn't know that Taroo didn't go.
```

The clause 太郎が行かなかった 'Taroo didn't go' is nominalized, and hence the accusative case particle を can attach.

The answer to your question then is: の in ～（な）のに is a nominal particle that produces nouns, or nominal expressions. Therefore, some linguists call it a **particle noun** (e.g. [Jens Rickmeyer](http://webcatplus.nii.ac.jp/webcatplus/details/creator/442125.html)).

Comment: What does it mean for something to be inflected?

Comment: Also, if it doesn't follow from meaning composition, then how did it acquire its meaning?

Comment: I would analyse the に as the 連用形 of なり rather than the allative/locative, but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: @Sjiveru That's how Martin analyzes it in his 1975 *Reference Grammar of Japanese* (p.858): "In the third meaning of the の-nominalization—'fact (etc.)'―に occurs as the essive (or copula infinitive) with a special implication: 'despite the fact that'".

Comment: For a similar sense of に, how about 何々だろうに（～かろうに）?

Comment: @Anthony Re inflection. That's a standard notion in linguistics. Please look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection). In Japanese, the inflected word classes are verbs and _i_-adjectives.

Comment: @Anthony Re compositionality. How does the meaning of the idiom _kick the bucket_ arise thru composition? - Not at all. That type of meaning is called _non-compositional_, the meaning having _lexicalized_, similar to grammaticalization. See [here](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/compositionality/) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_compositionality) for the general idea of compositionality.

Comment: @Brandon Yes, in a similar sense. There, too, the meaning is expressed by the future/prospective _plus_ に. It's difficult to assign one of these items priority in meaning.

Comment: How about the following explanation why の + に can mean のに? に can mark [cause, reason](https://www.japanesewithanime.com/2019/05/ni-particle.html#cause), and maybe even [source](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/99926/18894). So basically you have AにB, and B follows from A or somehow comes from it. A is "he was attacked," B is "he acted calmly." B doesn't follow from A, but sort of comes from it (they're linked). He was attacked and in that situation he acted calmly. What kind of link is that? "Even though" is the only possible explanation....

Comment: ...I.e. if に can mark A as some sort of source, linking A and B in some unspecified way, then "even though" interpretation becomes possible.